# Cpanel - There is another upcp process running

Tags: cpanel, whm

I have this error when i try to use cpanel upgrade to new version

```
There is another upcp process running, and you are watching the log from the existing process.
```

And then in box i see

```
Unable to find log file: /var/cpanel/updatelogs/last
```

please help how can i terminate as `ps aux | grep upcp`  shows no process running. I also have deleted `update_in_progress.txt` from `/usr/local/cpanel`. I am able to access tweak settings but not able to upgrade. Also tried `upcp --force`. Please help

Answer (score 0):

If */scripts/upcp --force* is not working, then I think your best option is to reboot the server and run it again.

Comment: I did reboot as well doesnt fix the problem. From where it is taking the information that another update is running.